# Sorting js array containing number as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a js array like this

```
[
  { id: '111111', wbs: '1'},
  {
    id: '22222222222',wbs: '1.2.1'},
  { id: '3333333333', wbs: '10'},
  { id: '4444444444', wbs: '2.1.1.1.1'},
  { id: '55555555555', wbs: '6'}
]
```

I want to sort it like below

```
[
      { id: '111111', wbs: '1'},
      {
        id: '22222222222',wbs: '1.2.1'},
      { id: '4444444444', wbs: '2.1.1.1.1'},
      { id: '55555555555', wbs: '6'}
      { id: '3333333333', wbs: '10'},
    ]
```

I have tried to use

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.wbs - b.wbs;
                    });
```

and

```
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
                    console.log(newWBS.sort(collator.compare));
```

but both do not give me the desired result. Need help on it.
Thank you

Comment: numbers with multiple decimal places aren't valid numbers. That aside, you can do e.g. `return (+a.wbs) - (+b.wbs);` to have js attempt to cast it as a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    { id: '111111', wbs: '1'},
    { id: '22222222222',wbs: '1.2.1'},
    { id: '3333333333', wbs: '10'},
    { id: '4444444444', wbs: '2.1.1.1.1'},
    { id: '55555555555', wbs: '6'}
];

// This function changes 2.5.7.9.3 to 2.5793, etc
function fixNumber(num) {
    const n = num.split(".");
    n[0] = `${n[0]}.`;
    return Number(n.length > 1 ? n.join("") : n[0]);
}

// sort the list
data.sort(
    (x, y) => fixNumber(x.wbs) - fixNumber(y.wbs)
)

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked as needed.

Comment: This indeed works great. However, what happens when one of the numbers beyond the first Tier is longer than a single digit?